# How to change touch screen functionality from a relative to an absolute pointing device?

Tags: multi-touch, touchscreen

I'm using a Serial Wacom Tablet touch device on an HP EliteBook 2740p.

The capacitive finger touch device (Serial Wacom Tablet touch) works, but is set to relative positioning instead of absolute. This means it works like a touchpad rather than a touch screen. System Settings has options for the pen portion of the touch screen, but I can't find any settings for the touch part. Is there anyway to configure the touch screen to work as an absolute pointing device?

Thanks

This is the output of xinput:

> :~$ xinput --list ⎡ Virtual core pointer
>     id=2    [master pointer  (3)] ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer
>     id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless
>   PID:1017  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse
>     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
>     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ Serial Wacom Tablet stylus
>     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ Serial Wacom Tablet eraser
>     id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ Serial Wacom Tablet touch
>     id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎣ Virtual core keyboard
>     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
>       ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Sleep Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ HP Webcam [2 MP Macro]                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the site of the wacom linux open source drivers:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Main_Page

The following page describes a set of commands that can change teh configuration of the tablet during runtime:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Tablet_Configuration

my guess is that the command you need is:

```
xsetwacom set "device name" Mode Absolute
```

where "device name" should be replaced by the name of the tablet, obtained by

```
xsetwacom --list devices
```

make sure you use the name that includes "touch" in it e.g.
"Wacom BambooFun 2FG 4x5 Finger touch"

then the command would be

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom BambooFun 2FG 4x5 Finger touch" Mode Absolute
```

Comment: wow that was easy. there really should be a setting for this in System Settings though.

Comment: hmm. the change does not persist across sleep or restart. Any ideas?